# Angular: how to programmatically set Base64 image as background image of a div

Tags: angular, base64, background-image, sanitization, ng-style

I have a `div` in which I show a Base64 image using CSS:

```
.my-image {
    background: url('data:image/jpg;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==');
}
```

Now this image could be different because I retrieve it from back-end so I have to change it dinamically.

So I have removed CSS and I have tried some solution in the component such as the following:

```
<div [style.background]="'url(' + myImage + ')'"></div>

<div [ngStyle]="{'background-image':'url('+ myImage +')'}"></div>
```

and some others... but none worked.

I have also sanitized the image in the component, using some methods of `DomSanitizer` like this:

```
this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.myImage)
```

But even this doesn't do the trick :(

Do you know a working way to have `div` with dynamic background image?

Here is my CSS now:

```
div {
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
}
```

Comment: did u checked value of `myImage`?

Comment: Did you set height?

Comment: Yes to both answers.

Comment: Can you provide the StackBlitz of the issue please?

Comment: Here is a StackBlitz with my image: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jzmbcs

Answer (score 7):

I don't know why, but ngStyle removes first ";" it encounters in URL

My brilliant solution to this is pretty simple:

Turn this

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-image':'url('+ myImage +')'}"
```

Turn into this

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-image':'url(;'+ myImage +')'}"
```

Just aaded ; as first char in the url

Comment: You are brilliant, after two hours of digging why. This is the best solution ever!!! Thanks!

Comment: Ye, I gave up after 10 minutes :P Sometimes it's more productive to have an ugly hack...you just achieve more within the same amount of time.

Answer (score 4):

Try like this:

.ts

```
myImage  = 'data:image/jpg;base64, iVBORw0KGgoA.....';
```

.html

```
<div [style.background-image]="'url(' + myImage  + ')'"> </div>
```

.css

```
div {
  height:500px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-13hue6?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: I think the difference is in my CSS.: I have `em` instead of `px` for width/height. Using `em` make it not to work... why?

Comment: I think em is used for only font-size

Comment: Even using `px` it is not working in my case: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jzmbcs

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem as you and I solved it by using double semicolon `;;` after the image extension, like this:

```
data:image/jpg;;base64
```

For some reason, in Angular 9 or earlier the string inside `ngStyle` directive was being rendered without any semicolon, `like data:image/jpgbase64`. The problem was solved, but I'd still like to know why it started to happen.